# Retrieve values from JSON string in PHP side

Tags: php, json

I was confused that I am no idea for this problem. 
 I am trying to retrieve the JSON string that posted from Android via httppost method. The string received in PHP side like below:

```
{"email": "abcde@xxxxxx.com","psw":"efgh"}
```

How to retrieve the namepairs value ? 
I want to the "email" and "psw" values can be saved to $email and  $psw variable in PHP.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: You've tagged the question with the right function, [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode), so what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json_decode.

```
$json = '{"email": "abcde@xxxxxx.com","psw":"efgh"}';
print_r(json_decode($json, true));
```